Overcoming posterior correlation for a model with random effects (for a Gibbs sampler)
I am trying to infer parameters for a model of case numbers of different infectious diseases in different locations over time. The model is
$$
\log \left(1 + y_{ijt}\right)\sim\mathsf{Normal}\left(\mu + z_t + a_i + b_j + A_{it} + B_{jt} + C_{ij},\tau^{-1}_{ij}\right),
$$
where

$y_{ijt}$ is the number of cases of disease $j$ in location $i$ in week $t$,
$\mu$ is the grand mean,
$z_t$ captures common temporal variation (e.g., due to population growth or holidays affecting reporting),
$a_i$ captures location-specific effects (e.g., due to greater population in one area compared with another),
$b_j$ captures disease-specific effects (e.g., due to some diseases being more common than others),
$A_{it}$ captures location-specific temporal effects (e.g., due to population changes in a particular area),
$B_{jt}$ captures disease-specific temporal effects (e.g., due to an outbreak of a particular disease),
$C_{ij}$ captures location-disease interactions (e.g., due to differential prevalence of a disease in a particular location),
and $\tau_{ij}^{-1}$ is the residual variance not explained by the model.

The crux is that only the sum of all the parameters is identified by the data, leading to strong anti-correlation between parameters (e.g., between $\mu$ and $z$) and strong positive correlation amongst parameters in the same "block" (e.g., between $z_1$ and $z_2$). This complicates posterior inference using most standard approaches. For example, using Stan's No-U-Turn sampler leads to large treedepth and slow mixing, mean-field variational inference leads to both slow convergence and also severely underestimates the posterior variance, and Gibbs samplers mix slowly due to the narrow conditional distributions. How can I sample from this posterior more efficiently? Gibbs sampling has worked the best so far (but the autocorrelation of samples is very large).
I have a diffuse prior on $\mu$, shrinkage priors on $a$, $b$, and $C$, a random walk priors on $z$, and independent random walk priors on each row of $A$ and $B$.
My attempts so far
We can make some progress by collapsing $z_t'=\mu + z_t$, $A_{it}'=a_i + A_{it}$, and $B_{jt}'=b_j + B_{jt}$ by appropriately modifying the prior variance for the first innovation of the random walks. Then the model simplifies somewhat to
$$
\log \left(1 + y_{ijt}\right)\sim\mathsf{Normal}\left(z'_t + A'_{it} + B'_{jt} + C_{ij},\tau^{-1}_{ij}\right),
$$
but collapsing further is tricky because we would have to define a prior on the collapsed variable. This quickly becomes computationally difficult because further collapsing leads to high-dimensional collapsed variables. I have about a hundred diseases, a few hundred locations, and a few hundred weeks. So the fully collapsed variable would have a few million parameters (but the prior would of course have low rank).
Reparameterization to $s_{ij} = a_i + b_j$ and $d_{ij} = a_i - b_j$ is often recommended for models of this kind. But, similar to collapsing discussed above, priors on the reparameterized variables become computationally cumbersome.
Parameter expansion to break (or alleviate) the correlation seems like a possibility, but I struggled to find an expansion that would have the desired effect; first time I'm trying to use a parameter expansion in earnest.
Any ideas would be much appreciated!

This question is hard to answer in the abstract. The outcome $y_{ijt}$ is discrete (number of cases); why are you using a normal model? Have you considered something like splines or a Gaussian process for the time and location? It may help and first build a model for say one disease and expand from there.

Thanks for the comments. I'm using a log1p-normal approximation as a prototype. The counts are large enough for most samples that a normal approximation to a Poisson/negative binomial model is acceptable–to be improved once the prototype fits. Splines and GPs do not alleviate the challenge because the additive degeneracy remains. Fitting a single disease is easier because the condition number of the posterior covariance is smaller (fewer degenerate terms). However, the aim of the project is to fit them all together to identify common patterns. Apologies for the terse response; character limit.
